Is there any way to keep stacktrace readable and avoid obfuscating that?
Im sending crash's stacktrace to my server, when i use r8 and obfuscate, the stacktrace goes illegible an unreadable like this:
java.lang.Exception: button crash
at fa.p.d(:63)
at ra.h.d(:49)
at o.w.k(:531)
at w.c3.m(:134)
at je.a.q(:9)
at je.f.z(:79)
at bf.h.s(:100)
at bf.h.G(:33)
at bf.h.q(:17)
at p1.p0.H0(:51)
at p1.p0.Z(:31)
at v.e.Z(:5)
at v.c0.Z(:3)
at p1.i.f(:157)
at p1.i.f(:136)
at p1.i.f(:136)
at p1.i.f(:136)
at p1.i.f(:136)
at p1.i.f(:136)
at p1.e.b(:30)
at p1.y.a(:122)
at v1.x.E(:79)
at v1.x.l(:214)

is there any way to keep stacktrace readable?
Note: i tried these in my proguard file:
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

But there was no difference.

You're not forgetting to actually retrace them right?

@Pawel Yeah, there is no way to keep readable and not retrace?

Not if you want to keep obfuscation enabled.
